# Configure Linux to allow network activity based on binary?

Tags: firewalls

On Windows, rules can be added to the firewall to allow/deny network traffic based on which binary is sending/receiving the data.  Can this be done on a Linux box, and if not, why not?  Is it a bad idea *per se*, or is it just not something that the makers of Linux thought of?

Comment: Very hard to implement, it should rely on a checksum + name to identify connections. Then the network stack has to be modified to intercept any call (or use k/ptrace) to send(). Then the system must interact with the user (many different DE/WM, no clean interface guarantied) and then change (permanently?) the ruleset of the packet filter to authorize accepted connections. It's more complex than that actually but this should let you understand why there is no such thing on UNIX yet (as I know). BTW, the program can still call another legitimate program to reach out, and users make mistakes...

Comment: @Aki Windows has it; I guess Microsoft are just more determined to make a secure firewall, eh?  :-)  Surely `iptables` could be upgraded to allow this.

Comment: they only have one Desktop Environment, which makes it easy to integrate notification from the kernel. By design in Unix systems userland is strictly separated from the kernel. System calls can be used to ask the kernel specific tasks (access to IO, etc). One could imagine this kind of improvement on some distribution of Linux, but I doubt this would get accepted upstream. It's not just iptable to upgrade and maintain. A firewall doesn't run application, so no need to deny/accept anything interactively, a firewall should be a headless (CLI) and at the network border.

Comment: Moreover, the 'firewall' on windows, is more an antivirus/malware/etc than a firewall (packet filter).

Comment: Why would it need to do anything "interactively"?  These binary rules could be set up in advance like all other firewall rules.

Comment: @Aki "_Very hard to implement, it should rely on a checksum + name to identify connections._" what's wrong with simply using the process image path?

Comment: @Aki "_By design in Unix systems userland is strictly separated from the kernel._" Hug? what design are you talking about?

Comment: @Aki "_Moreover, the 'firewall' on windows, is more an antivirus/malware/etc than a firewall (packet filter)._" What do you mean?

Comment: @Jez: Because you don't want to calculate the checksum manually for each binary (especially if you upgrade them often as you usually do on linux). Without this, cp malware /tmp/firefox will bypass your security.

Comment: @curiousguy: A firewall is just a packet filter, it only pays attention to network traffic, and not to application running. Moreover, firewalls are not usually workstations, but dedicated machines who filter traffic, you don't run any program you don't know/trust on it like you'd do on a workstation. Userland is separated from the kernel, "The Linux kernel is developed and maintained separately from userland." http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Guide_to_Unix/Linux#Kernel This is true for all UNIX-like systems.

Comment: BTW, I'd guess that windows implement this as a antivirus, by placing hooks on network library functions. Which with some level of reverse engineering, can be bypassed. There are many ways to bypass it, it's not a cutting edge security feature at all, it's here to cut down malware infection which is very important on windows. Maybe it'll change in your favorite distribution over time, but for now, it's not a good idea.

Comment: @Aki "_cp malware /tmp/firefox will bypass your security_" can you explain? "_A firewall is just a packet filter, it only pays attention to network traffic, and not to application running._" A firewall cannot "pay attention" to processes? says who? "_you don't run any program you don't know/trust on it like you'd do on a workstation._" so you run untrusted programs? :o "The Linux kernel is developed and maintained separately from userland." I still have no idea what this means.

Comment: @curiousguy: Hum, it's too long to demonstrate and explain thoroughly, some pointers: a program name can be changed, a firewall is a packet filter, packets are going though the network cards and pass a filter before being processed, this is what a firewall does. As a matter of fact no, I am careful, but others aren't and need this feature. Linux is a kernel, it just takes care of hardware basically, an OS is more than that, it's all the programs that run: WM, DE, web browser, shell, etc. Different people work on these, the kernel is a whole world apart which just provides interfaces.

Comment: @Aki "_I am careful, but others aren't and need this feature._" If people are installing and running pretty much any program they find on the interweb, then they have some serious security issues, and a firewall can hardly fix that. Anyway, these users will run the installer with full rights so what prevents the installer from messing with firewall settings? So I just don't find this defence method realistic. Also, as I said I my answer, an untrusted program can easily mess with a trusted program to make it do what it wants.

Comment: @curiousguy: I think people need an antivirus/malware/etc for this feature, and they should leave packet filtering to packet filters (known as firewall). You can accept/deny/drop connections without touching the packet filter. It will come on Linux since it's becoming very popular, but really not yet

Answer (score 5):

This can be done via [SELinux](http://static.usenix.org/event/usenix01/freenix01/full_papers/loscocco/loscocco_html/node10.html). There are [examples here](http://securityblog.org/brindle/2007/05/28/secure-networking-with-selinux/).

Comment: Too tired now to go Google'ing, but I've seen iptables modules that can identify binaries, UID/GID. I'm of to bed now.

Answer (score 3):

> Is it a bad idea per se

It is a bad idea to **discriminate on process image** and expect to gain some sort of security from that, if you do not protect these processes.

## Executable image whitelist

For example, say you only allow wget and curl and block all other network accesses. You might think that this security setting allows arbitrary HTTP/s, FTP, etc. requests, but not sending arbitrary data via TCP, or starting arbitrary TCP servers sockets, or using UDP. But because wget and curl are ordinary dynamically linked non Set-something programs, they can be :

- started with arbitrary `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, started with a modified dynamic loader, any tricks ltrace does
- traced, as `strace` does
- modified at runtime with `ptrace`(2)

As `strace`/`ltrace` do, you can manipulate any process unless it runs with a different user or group ID, or with capabilities you do not have.

If you want to associate *any* specific rights to specific images (f.ex. `/usr/bin/wget`), you should protect processes launched from interference as strongly as set-something processes are protected. Unless this is properly done, you mostly have security theatre and protection from non-adaptive threats (which is perhaps all that you need, but you should explicitly say so).

Of course you can only protect a process if it is designed to be protected from its user, and most programs are not. In particular most browsers allow the installation of arbitrary extensions which are allowed to access the network, all from the browser process, with the process's rights, sometimes with no specific security restriction whatsoever, so you would also have to prevent installation of extensions in whitelisted programs.

## Executable image blacklist

OTOH, you may use the firewall to prevent specific daemons from accessing the network, or opening any unexpected connections.

To enforce these restriction, you need at least to :

- prevent restricted processes from starting unrestricted processes
- prevent restricted processes from interfering (as above) with unrestricted processes

Starting arbitrary executable images is done with `exec`, and the kernel should either prevent restricted processes from launching unrestricted images, or tag the new process so that it is restricted as its parents.

But an executable image can also be indirectly done by adding `cron`/`anacron`/`at`/`batch` jobs, so restricted process should be prevented from editing job lists, possibly by making sure that they do not own the jobs lists files, and have no write access to them. Any user might also procmailrc, and run arbitrary commands whenever mail is received, etc.

These restriction have to be integrated OS-wide, not just kernel-wide. This goes against Unix tradition where any process with a user-ID is expected allowed to start any process with its user-ID, and the `cron`/`at`/maildrop DAEMONs/programs have integrated this assumption. You have to look for any daemon that starts programs on user behalf, and blacklist these features.

See the pattern? **Enforcement of a blacklist of specific processes preventing specific system calls (network access) leads to more backlists not only on other system calls (`exec` family) but also on other OS components.** Any secure, Unix-reasonable (that is: whose behaviour is fully expected under a traditional Unix system) DAEMON can introduce a security loophole.

## Conclusion

The "kernel" of the kernel (the micro-kernel part of a monolithic kernel) must know about process rights, not just a specific subsystem (network subsystem, file-system, etc.). The "right to network" is an essential property of a process, just like user-IDs or the capability set.

*Or you can say that all you need is a protection from non-adaptive threats: you are afraid of standard worms/viruses, not targeted attacks.*

**This is a general problem in any retrofitted security feature.**

### Personal conclusion

This is why I think that capabilities is fundamentally a terribly broken idea. Unix is based on user-ID: if you want security isolation, use a different UID. This resource is cheap.

Comment: I wouldn't envisage this as being used to implement a blacklist (if you don't trust the binary, why is it even on your system?)  BTW, what on earth is a "set-something program"?

Comment: @Jez "_I wouldn't envisage this as being used to implement a blacklist (if you don't trust the binary, why is it even on your system?)_" why do you need a firewall if you trust your system? "_BTW, what on earth is a "set-something program"?_" ever heard of set-UID, set-GID, set-cap?